# Spring MVC <input:form> does not allow name attribute to be used. Causes hindrance when working with javascript document.getElementsByName()?

Tags: java, javascript, spring, spring-mvc

Here is my spring mvc jsp code snippet

```
<c:forEach var="trackRecord"  varStatus = "number" items="${contractDetails.trackRecordEntries}" >
  <tr class="tafont">
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" name = "installmentNo" id = "installmentNo" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].installmentNo"/></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" name  = "installmentAmount" id = "installmentAmount" path = "trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].installmentAmount"/></td>   
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" name = "dueDate" id = "dueDate" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].dueDate"/></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input cssClass="recievedDate" name = "recievedDate" id = "recievedDate" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].recievedDate"/></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input id = "recieptAmount" name = "recieptAmount" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].recieptAmount"/></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input id = "delayDays" name = "delayDays" path="trackRecordEntries[${number.index}].delayDays"/></td>     
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

It binds an arraylist of bean to the jsp page. Problem is i cannot use '`name`' attribute with `<form:input>` tag. I need the name attribute to be there because i want to perform javascript validation using `document.getElementsByName("name");`

Any Solution ??

Comment: Use the `id` or `class` attributes. The name is used by spring for data-binding (the `path` is extended and put into the name attribute).  So either do the lookup by `id` or add a specific class to the input (just for selection).

Comment: I cannot look up by id. because there is no document.getElementsByid("ID"); function in javascript  i have to loop through array of elements. How can i use class to achieve the same?

Comment: Instead of the name simply add a class and use `document.getElementsByClassName`.

Comment: path attribute does the job for me. See Ashish answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are using Spring tags (i.e `<form:input>`) tags then you can not use **name** attribute in spring tags.If you want **name** attribute then you have to use **path** attribute of  tag which internally convert its value to **name** attribute of an **HTML** tag as follows :

```
<c:forEach var="trackRecord"  varStatus = "number" items="${contractDetails.trackRecordEntries}" >
  <tr class="tafont">
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" path = "installmentNo" id = "installmentNo" /></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" path  = "installmentAmount" id = "installmentAmount" /></td>   
      <td class="varcar"><form:input readonly = "true" path = "dueDate" id = "dueDate" /></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input cssClass="recievedDate" path = "recievedDate" id = "recievedDate" /></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input id = "recieptAmount" path = "recieptAmount" /></td>
      <td class="varcar"><form:input id = "delayDays" path = "delayDays" /></td>     
 </tr>
 </c:forEach>
```

and you have to define all this path variable into your form like follows:

```
public class UoyrForm {

    private String[] installmentNo;
    private String[] installmentAmount;
    private String[] dueDate;
    private String[] recievedDate;
    private String[] recieptAmount;
    private String[] delayDays;
}
```

or you can use simple HTML tags to

Comment: i want to use name attribute so that i can use it to get list of elements in javascript. Please read the question

Comment: @AbhishekSingh please check your page source code then you will come to know that Spring tags "path" attribute is converted into HTML "name" attribute that's why spring tag does not support "name" attribute

Comment: @AbhishekSingh is this a working code ? How can you specify dynamic value to Spring tags path attribute ?

Answer (score 0):

why dont you use document.getElementById("id value here"), since you have unique id values defined, and name attribute is reduntant here