# Spring MVC : prevent rendering ModelAttribute value in jsp by using form:input

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a button when user click it, it will retrieve a row of data from table, and populate the data into a form. Illustrate picture below.
[image]

I have successful retrieved table row data.

The problem is I can't render the data into `form:input` by using jquery `$('#x').value('some value');` or javascript `document.getElementById('x').value = "some value";`

**Working Code**

1) Implemented in normal form which is `<input id="x"/>`. It's work with jquery or javascript. (when button is pressed, I could get row data)

2) Implemented in `<form:input value="x"/>`. Value x can be rendered.

**Problem Code**

```
<form:form modelAttribute="command" method="POST" action="link">
    <form:input path="url" id="x"/>
</form:form>
```

**Suspect** Rendering Sequences : Jquery => modelAttribute => `<form:input value="?"/>`

**What I want to do**
I want to render value in form:form & also want return modelAttribute value from VIEW jsp back to controller.

**Solution** If my suspect is correct and prevent rendering modelAttribute is work, then javascript rendering value should not be overrided by form:form modelAttribute.

Comment: Suppose that I'm an Idiot. Now, Just tell me that "Where are you taking the form data?" Server(JSP) or Client(JQuery/JavaScript). Coz, You're just explaining the JQuery & JS.

Comment: Controller will take form data.
I want form:input value taking from my table row but not modelAttribute

Comment: <form:form modelAttribute="command" action="x">
        <form:input path="url"/>
    </form:form>

<form:form> will render data from modelAttribute from a class Object. 
It will override value retrieved from row table by using jquery.

Comment: Overall, You want a data from id="x" in a JSP..?

Comment: yes, it also allow user to change the value.

Comment: Oops.. You miss a Concept.. id="x" can't to taken to a Server.. So, You'll need name="x" to work on JSP.

Comment: id="x" is used at client-side, name="x" will be used at Server Side.. Use: **<form:input path="url" id="x" name="x">**

Comment: <form:input> not allow to have 'name' , using path instead of name ***please read***
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18998598/spring-mvc-inputform-does-not-allow-name-attribute-to-be-used-causes-hindran

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, I haven't found any solution to prevent modelAttribute to rendering it's value.

JQuery (`$('#x').val('some value')`) & JS (`document.getElementById(x).value = 'some value'`) is work fine in `<form:input/>`. means `<form:input>` could get the value by using JQuery or JS.

And

To correct my suspect : rendering sequences jquery > modelAttribute > form:input value="?" which is wrong.

**Situation :** Multiple `<form:form>`

**Solution :**

Cautions : When you have multiple `<form:form>`, `<form:input path="x">` path should not have same path name. Otherwise, you only rendering the path value at the top of JSP.